# What is the current state of preconditioning highly heterogeneous equations? Where do I start?

Tags: finite-element, preconditioning

Consider the simple standard Laplacian in 2D or 3D:
$$\nabla (\alpha \nabla u) =f $$

with $\alpha$ being a scalar. $\alpha$ can take values that can vary largely between 1e-8 and 1 throughout the domain. After discritizing the equation above with FEM one arrives at a linear system which will encounter convergence difficulties if a standard iterative solver is used.

Problems like these arise an highly heterogeneous media and require special treatment for the iterative solver. What are the current techniques out there? How do they compare in terms of performance, scalability, and ease of application? Where can I start?

Comment: What's wrong with (algebraic or geometric) multigrid? If you average appropriately on coarser levels, they can solve such problems just fine.

Comment: My knowledge about these techniques is very surface level. It would be wise to ask about the limitations and alternatives and how do they compare.